# key_load_public: invalid format

Tags: git, github, ssh, public-key

I used PuTTY Key Generator to generate a 4096 bit RSA-2 key with a passphrase.

I save the .ppk and an openSSL format public key. The putty format public key doesn't work.

In any case, my error is as follows:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
key_load_public: invalid format
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Dan/.ssh/id_rsa':
Hi Dan! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

What's the issue?

I use Pageant to load the keys and i use Git Bash to try the ssh connection. I've also loaded the key into GitHub, not sure what i'm doing wrong.

I've tried adding a new line and not adding a new line in GitHub

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't work? It says *successfully authenticated*.

Comment: @RolandSmith It's telling me `key_load_public: invalid format` right as i execute the command before i enter the passphrase?

Comment: Do: 'ssh -vvv -T git@github.com' to get more info, probably ~/.ssh/known_hosts is bad - ssh is looking for github's public key.  You can run 'file key' to find out key file's format.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

As [Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42864089/3068190) mentioned in their answer, it's a warning that the `ssh-agent` doesn't understand the format of the public key and even then, the public key will not be used locally.

However, I can also elaborate and answer why the warning is there. It simply boils down to the fact that the *PuTTY Key Generator* generates **two different public key formats** depending on what you do in the program.

**Note:** Throughout my explanation, the key files I will be using/generating will be named `id_rsa` with their appropriate extensions. Furthermore, for copy-paste convenience, the parent folder of the keys will be assumed to be `~/.ssh/`. Adjust these details to suit your needs as desired.

### The Formats

[Link to the relevant PuTTY documentation](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.69/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#puttygen-savepub)

#### SSH-2

When you **save** a key using the *PuTTY Key Generator* using the "Save public key" button, it will be saved in the format defined by [RFC 4716](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4716#section-3).

Example:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "github-example-key"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAhl/CNy9wI1GVdiHAJQV0CkHnMEqW7+Si9WYF
i2fSBrsGcmqeb5EwgnhmTcPgtM5ptGBjUZR84nxjZ8SPmnLDiDyHDPIsmwLBHxcp
pY0fhRSGtWL5fT8DGm9EfXaO1QN8c31VU/IkD8niWA6NmHNE1qEqpph3DznVzIm3
oMrongEjGw7sDP48ZTZp2saYVAKEEuGC1YYcQ1g20yESzo7aP70ZeHmQqI9nTyEA
ip3mL20+qHNsHfW8hJAchaUN8CwNQABJaOozYijiIUgdbtSTMRDYPi7fjhgB3bA9
tBjh7cOyuU/c4M4D6o2mAVYdLAWMBkSoLG8Oel6TCcfpO/nElw==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

#### OpenSSH

Contrary to popular belief, this format doesn't get saved by the generator. However it is generated and shown in the text box titled "Public key for pasting into OpenSSH authorized_keys file". To save it as a file, you have to manually copy it from the text box and paste it into a new text file.

For the key shown above, this would be:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAhl/CNy9wI1GVdiHAJQV0CkHnMEqW7+Si9WYFi2fSBrsGcmqeb5EwgnhmTcPgtM5ptGBjUZR84nxjZ8SPmnLDiDyHDPIsmwLBHxcppY0fhRSGtWL5fT8DGm9EfXaO1QN8c31VU/IkD8niWA6NmHNE1qEqpph3DznVzIm3oMrongEjGw7sDP48ZTZp2saYVAKEEuGC1YYcQ1g20yESzo7aP70ZeHmQqI9nTyEAip3mL20+qHNsHfW8hJAchaUN8CwNQABJaOozYijiIUgdbtSTMRDYPi7fjhgB3bA9tBjh7cOyuU/c4M4D6o2mAVYdLAWMBkSoLG8Oel6TCcfpO/nElw== github-example-key
```

The format of the key is simply `ssh-rsa <signature> <comment>` and can be created by rearranging the SSH-2 formatted file.

### Regenerating Public Keys

If you are making use of `ssh-agent`, you will likely also have access to `ssh-keygen`.

If you have your OpenSSH Private Key (`id_rsa` file), you can generate the OpenSSH Public Key File using:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

If you only have the PUTTY Private Key (`id_rsa.ppk` file), you will need to convert it first.

1. Open the *PuTTY Key Generator*
2. On the menu bar, click "File" > "Load private key"
3. Select your `id_rsa.ppk` file
4. On the menu bar, click "Conversions" > "Export OpenSSH key"
5. Save the file as `id_rsa` (without an extension)

Now that you have an OpenSSH Private Key, you can use the `ssh-keygen` tool as above to perform manipulations on the key.

### Bonus: The PKCS#1 PEM-encoded Public Key Format

To be honest, I don't know what this key is used for as I haven't needed it. But I have it in my notes I've collated over the years and I'll include it here for wholesome goodness. The file will look like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCAKCAQEAhl/CNy9wI1GVdiHAJQV0CkHnMEqW7+Si9WYFi2fSBrsGcmqeb5Ew
gnhmTcPgtM5ptGBjUZR84nxjZ8SPmnLDiDyHDPIsmwLBHxcppY0fhRSGtWL5fT8D
Gm9EfXaO1QN8c31VU/IkD8niWA6NmHNE1qEqpph3DznVzIm3oMrongEjGw7sDP48
ZTZp2saYVAKEEuGC1YYcQ1g20yESzo7aP70ZeHmQqI9nTyEAip3mL20+qHNsHfW8
hJAchaUN8CwNQABJaOozYijiIUgdbtSTMRDYPi7fjhgB3bA9tBjh7cOyuU/c4M4D
6o2mAVYdLAWMBkSoLG8Oel6TCcfpO/nElwIBJQ==
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

This file can be generated using an OpenSSH Private Key (as generated in "Regenerating Public Keys" above) using:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y -e -m pem > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem
```

Alternatively, you can use an OpenSSH Public Key using:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -e -m pem > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem
```

##References:##

- ["key_load_public: invalid format..." on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/700172/618994)
- [The Secure Shell (SSH) Public Key File Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4716#section-3)
- [Converting OpenSSH public keys](http://blog.oddbit.com/2011/05/08/converting-openssh-public-keys/)

Comment: When you convert your private key to an OpenSSH key, It is in my opinion recommend to leave the file extensionless and not preferable. My git-client won't connect to the remote repository when an extension is used for the private key.

Comment: @Programmer1994 The conversion instructions were included as steps to convert the `.ppk` to a `.pub` file. The side effect of the intermediary `id_rsa` private key actually being used by another program was overlooked. I have changed the language "preferably extensionless" to "(without an extension)" to clear any ambiguity. I also took the chance to reword some grievances that come up whenever I look back at this answer. Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

I used the command in the section of your answer "Regenerating Public Keys" and it solved my problem.

Comment: you talked about public keys.
but the issue is generated from a private key id_rsa. I get the same warning when I use my private ssh key when attempting to access a git server via ssh.

Comment: `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` this solved it. THX!

Comment: very help, you save my hours ... :-D
I follow to Regenerating Public Keys, and yields me worked.

Comment: in my case I had an error in the public key file (although one might think it's not needed here) - the file contained a single key split into 3 lines for some reason (probably I incorrectly copied it from an editor)

Answer (score 42):

There is a simple solution if you can install and use puttygen tool. Below are the steps. You should have the passphrase of the private key.

step 1:
Download latest [puttygen](https://www.puttygen.com/) and open puttygen

step 2:
Load your existing private key file, see below image

[image: Load an existing private key]

step 3: Enter passphrase for key if asked and hit ok

[image: enter paasphrase]

step 4: as shown in the below image select "conversion" menu tab and select "Export OpenSSH key"

[image: save OpenSSH file]

Save new private key file at preferred location and use accordingly.

Comment: I got the `load pubkey invalid format` warning, when I exported the key with **Export OpenSSH key**. It went away when using **Export OpenSSH key (force new file format)**.

Comment: In linux, `apt install putty-tools` or `yum install putty` then `sudo puttygen private.ppk -O private-openssh-new -o private.pem`

Answer (score 14):

**TL;DR:** also ensure that your `id_rsa.pub` is in ascii / UTF-8.

I had the same problem, however [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44391850/11932910) alone did not work because of the text encoding, which was an additional, easy-to-miss issue.

When I run

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

in Windows PowerShell, it saves the output to `id_rsa.pub` in **UTF-16 LE BOM** encoding, not in **UTF-8**. This is a property of some installations of PowerShell, which was discussed in [Using PowerShell to write a file in UTF-8 without the BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom/5596984#5596984). Apparently, OpenSSH does not recognise the former text encoding and produces an identical error:

```
key_load_public: invalid format
```

Copying and pasting the output of `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y` into a text editor is the simplest way to solve this.

P.S. This could be an addition to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44391850/11932910), but I don't have enough karma to comment here yet.

Comment: As you discovered, piping works differently in Powershell. You would use `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y | ac ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` instead.

Answer (score 8):

In the case you copy your public key with clipboard and paste it, it may happen the public key string can be broken which contains new-line.

Make sure your public key string formed as one line.

Answer (score 8):

Generate id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files using the below command :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Then :

```
1) Place file in id_rsa.pub into ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

2) sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

3) Place file id_rsa into ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Now ~/.ssh contains two files..~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and ~/.ssh/id_rsa

4) ssh-add  ~/.ssh/id_rsa

5) Enter the passphrase entered during creation of id_rsa

Output :

Identity added: /home/jay/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/jay/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Now you can push pull without entering username password

Comment: This was really helpful. Had to place both files in same folder.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that `ssh` cannot read your public key. But that doesn't matter.

You upload your *public key* to github, but you authenticate using your *private key*. See e.g. the FILES section in `ssh(1)`.

Comment: In short, go to putty key gen, click conversions -> open ssh key and save that to id_rsa - make sure your HOME env variable is pointing to the .ssh folder you are looking at, delete all other copies of id_rsa file from  your system

Comment: This answer is the solution for me. See the same answer at [ssh key_load_public: invalid format warning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/590649/442338). You should rename or remove the public key on the client, as it is not needed anyway on the client, and it seems to be checked as a private key because it is named the same (just with extension ".pub").

Answer (score 4):

**Adding SSH-KEY in Git-hub: Windows**

Type this in cmd: `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your-email-id"`

Go to `C:\Users\your-name\.ssh`

There you will get a file: `id_ed25519.pub`

open that file , copy that , go to **github->setting->keys->ssh-key->new SSH Key**

There paste your copied key

Done!!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Windows 10 with the built-in SSH, as of August 2020 it only supports ed25519 keys. You'll get the `key_load_public: invalid format` error if you use e.g. an RSA key.

As per [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/973) it should be fixed via Windows Update some time in 2020. So one solution is to just wait for the update to ship.

If you can't wait, a workaround is to generate a new ed25519 key, which is [good advice anyway](https://medium.com/risan/upgrade-your-ssh-key-to-ed25519-c6e8d60d3c54).

```
> ssh-keygen -o -a 100 -t ed25519
```

You can use it with e.g. github, but some older systems might not support this newer format.

After generating your key, if you're using either of the below features, don't forget to update them!

1. `~\.ssh\config` might still point to the old key.
2. Add the new key to ssh-agent via the `ssh-add` command

Answer (score 3):

The error is misleading - it says "`pubkey`" while pointing to a private key file `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

In my case, it was simply a missing public key (as I haven't restored it  from a vault).

---

#### DETAILS

I used to skip deploying `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` by automated scripts.

All `ssh` usages worked, but the error made me think of a possible mess.

Not at all - `strace` helped to notice that the trigger was actually the **`*.pub`** file:

```
strace ssh example.com
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/uvsmtid/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
write(2, "load pubkey \"/home/uvsmtid/.ssh/"..., 57) = 57
load pubkey "/home/uvsmtid/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of directly saving the private key Go to Conversions and Export SSh Key.
Had the same issue and this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same warning. It was a very old key. I regenerated a key on the current OpenSSH 7, and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

So, after update I had the same issue. I was using PEM `key_file` without extension and simply adding `.pem` fixed my issue. Now the file is `key_file.pem`.

Answer (score 0):

@uvsmtid Your post finally lead me into the right `direction`:
simply deleting (actually renaming) the public key file `id_rsa.pub` solved the problem for me, that git was working though nagging about *invalid format*.
Not quite sure, yet the file is not actually needed, since the pub key can be extracted from private key file `id_rsa` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error `Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format` when I tried

```
RUN echo "$ssh_prv_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa &&     chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This led to errors like `identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1 invalid format` and `read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty`.

The right way would be to use

```
COPY id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The solution explained: my private key was wrongly formatted - instead of many lines, it was passed as a one-liner, and you might have any other format issue like a forgotten "-" at the start or end, or something wrong at the end of the lines, like a missing newline format or an additional letter at the end of a line.

See [Dockerfile: clone repo with passwordless private key. Errors: “authentication agent” or “read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty”](https://superuser.com/questions/1633085/dockerfile-clone-repo-with-passwordless-private-key-errors-authentication-ag) for more details, with the main idea from [Add private key to ssh-agent in docker file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56400527/11154841), which again had the idea from [Gitlab CI/Docker: ssh-add keeps asking for passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829291/nohup-causes-read-passphrase-cant-open-dev-tty/66647740#66647740).

Answer (score 0):

I had the error to use as IdentityFile `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/KEYNAME.pub` instead of `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/KEYNAME` in

ssh does not check those things in a user-friendly way, even though the config is wrong and not the file.
I checked that with `ssh-keygen -l -f .ssh/KEYNAME.pub`.

ssh -V was `OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`.