# can't git clone in pythonanywhere -- permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to clone a repo into PythonAnywhere, but I'm getting a permission denied (publickey) error.

I followed the instructions on Pythonanywhere to set up ssh keys and pasted them into GitHub like normal, but I'm still receiving the error.

```
git clone git@github.com:hackerlikecomputer/CPD-Adult-Arrests-Scraper.git                                             
Cloning into 'CPD-Adult-Arrests-Scraper'...                                                                                                                                           
key_load_public: invalid format                                                                                                                                                       
Permission denied (publickey).                                                                                                                                                        
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                                                                                                         

Please make sure you have the correct access rights                                                                                                                                   
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Make sure you are cloning with the correct user (i.e. the user you created the ssh keys for). Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863913/key-load-public-invalid-format
Try create a new set of keys i.e. `ssh-keygen -t ed25119` (or whatever type). Then `cat ~/.ssh/id_25519.pub`. Copy paste output to github SSH key area

Comment: @Tagger5926 this should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are cloning with the correct user (i.e. the user you created the ssh keys for).

Also this might be relevant: [key_load_public: invalid format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863913/key-load-public-invalid-format)

Another thing you can try is create a new set of keys i.e. `ssh-keygen -t ed25119` (or whatever type). Then `cat ~/.ssh/id_25519.pub`. Copy paste output to github SSH key area

Just in case something is corrupt or not generated properly.