# BATCH file to connect to Linux via SSH. How?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, openssh

First a screenshot that shows OpenSSH installed on Windows 10...

[image: ssh]

Above, I use the command `ssh -V` in the command prompt to make sure OpenSSH is installed.

**Now..** It appears that throwing the following one liner into a `.bat` file to login to a linux server via ssh doesn't do anything.

```
ssh -p 22 root@10.10.1.100
```

**When I type the same one liner** into a windows 10 command prompt since Windows 10 now has OpenSSH built in, **it logs me in just fine.**

What I am missing?

Comment: Didn't work. With your approach the prompt thinks `ssh` is the hostname argument.

Comment: `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -p 22 root@10.10.1.100`

Comment: That works. So... is my answer below still appropriate or I should update with your solution since we aren't really focusing on PowerShell?

Comment: You can leave you answer, I will post another one with my solution.

Comment: Ok. You know... just before it authenticates successfully every time, there is this `key_load_public: invalid format`. This doesn't show when I use PuTTY. I wonder if it's a windows thing...

Comment: Did you setup public keys? if so, DSA or RSA?

Comment: Yeah. Then I use private key to connect and it works every time. It just... shows `key_load_public: invalid format`.

Comment: Rather fix it properly. See the [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863913/key-load-public-invalid-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do not name your batch file `ssh.bat` or `ssh.cmd` and it will probably be best if you use the full path to the executable:

```
@echo off
"C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -p 22 root@10.10.1.100
pause
```

but it is probably better to use the `%windir%` environment variable:

```
@echo off
"%windir%\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -p 22 root@10.10.1.100
pause
```