# docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)" returning empty

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, docker-image

I want to be able to read the contents of the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and pass the same to my build stage of the image. When I use the command `docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"` and then I try to echo that inside the container during a build, I get empty.

```
RUN echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > /priv_key \
    && cat /priv_key
```

the result is

```
Step 6/14 : RUN echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > /priv_key     && cat /priv_key
 ---> Running in c8d6e3c88cd8

Removing intermediate container c8d6e3c88cd8
```

In the dockerfile I have `ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`.

But when I use a dummy text like `docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="dummy text"` I can see it in the logs.

This causes my private key to be in invalid format since it is empty. 
`RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" >> /root/.ssh/id_rsa`

What am I doing wrong or what is it that am not doing? Thank you

Comment: That's strange. The problem isn't with Docker since `dummy text` works. `"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"` gets evaluated in the shell and gets passed to `docker build` just like `dummy text`. Does `echo "$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"` work?

Comment: It works on host - Mac OS.

Comment: Does it work with other files/what it you use absolute path instead of `~`?

Comment: Very Strange. Even that is not working.

Comment: I am on Mac OSX

Comment: and what about `docker build --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(echo something)"` / what shell do you use (`bash`, `zsh`, etc)?

Comment: This approach will compromise your ssh keys: anything you add to a Docker image can be trivially retrieved in plain text by anyone who has the image.  Whatever your higher-level goal is, I would strongly suggest looking for a way to do it that does not require calling ssh from within the Dockerfile.

Comment: Good point. What about attaching it as a volume when starting the container (if the key must be present in the docker container)?

Comment: I have use ONVAULT tool to handle the keys. Now it's working

Comment: @DavidMaze its possible to use it and not expose private key with intermediate images, which are removed after final image is built.

Answer (score 3):

I went ahead and used `ONVAULT` toool to handle the ssh keys. https://github.com/dockito/vault.

Also, I had misconfigured my `.ssh/config` file. The new file looks like this

```
Host *
  IgnoreUnknown AddKeysToAgent,UseKeychain
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I hope it helps someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by placing the `ARG` after defining the base image:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as builder
ARG SSH_PRV_KEY
```

instead of

```
ARG SSH_PRV_KEY
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as builder
```